# clang bug related to stdarg?

Tags: c, clang

This appears to be a bug in clang related to null terminated variable argument lists.

The expected behavior is that va_arg() will return 0 on the first iteration since the argument following alias is 0.

Complete code is below. In main(), removing "void *map = 0;" or the call to foo() makes the bug go away.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

/*
clang --version:
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
*/

void *foo(char *a, char *b, char *c, ...) {
        return 0;
}

void *bar(char *a, char *b, char *c, char *d, char *e, char *f, char *alias, ...) {
        char *arg;
        va_list ap;
        va_start(ap, alias);
        printf("alias = %s\n", alias);
        while((arg = va_arg(ap, char *))) {
                printf("arg = %p\n", arg);
                printf("BUG!\n");
                return 0;
        }
        va_end(ap);
        printf("NO BUG\n");
        return 0;
}

int main() {
        void *map = 0; // removing this statement hides bug
        foo(0, 0, 0, 0);// removing this statement hides bug
        bar("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "b", 0);
}
```

Output is:

```
alias = b
arg = 0x100000000
BUG!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`0` is not a `char*`; it's an `int`. So reading it with `va_arg(ap, char*)` is Undefined Behaviour.

Supply the argument `(char*)0` when you mean a null pointer of type `char *`. (Or `(char*)NULL`, if you prefer.) As M.M. points out in a comment, the commonly-seen `NULL` is not correct since `NULL` might be `#define`d as `0`.

(Since `0` is an `int`, the compiler doesn't worry about the high-order four bytes. The low-order four bytes of the argument are indeed 0. But that's an implementation detail; I only mention it by way of explanation.)

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate it. ( Knocks self in forehead. )

Comment: `NULL` might be a macro for `0` , so the `(char *)0` version should always be used (or `(char *)NULL`)